# HTTP Post By AJAX

Tags: ajax, http, post

I want to post some ad to CraigList webiste using this URL. https://post.craigslist.org/nyc/S/fud/mnh/all I know AJAX is a solution which can perform where there is no same origin policy restriction.

The unique thing about this URL is that it modifies the action attribute of the form every time you refresh the page and I can't just post to a single static URL. I wonder is there a way I can automate this URL using AJAX?

I am using JQuery and know how to post a URL but this is headache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to use AJAX as it violates the same origin policy. You can use a regular POST, but you will have to parse the page for the hidden fields etc. to make it work.

Craigslist has gone into a lot of problem to make automated posting very difficult, so I wouldn't bother.

Comment: more specifically the problem is when I call a URL using HTTP GET the firefox can retrieve the content with status 200 but says some XML parsing error which is annoying